# Encrypting appSettings in web.config

Tags: .net, security, encryption, web-applications, appsettings

I am developing a web app which requires a username and password to be stored in the web.Config, it also refers to some URLs which will be requested by the web app itself and never the client.

I know the .Net framework will not allow a web.config file to be served, however I still think its bad practice to leave this sort of information in plain text.

Everything I have read so far requires me to use a command line switch or to store values in the registry of the server.  I have access to neither of these as the host is online and I have only FTP and Control Panel (helm) access.

Can anyone recommend any good, free encryption DLL's or methods which I can use?  I'd rather not develop my own!

Thanks for the feedback so far guys but I am not able to issue commands and and not able to edit the registry.  Its going to have to be an encryption util/helper but just wondering which one!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- [Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) (ASP.NET) on MSDN
- [Encrypting Web.Config Values in ASP.NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx) on ScottGu's [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx)
- [Encrypting Custom Configuration Sections](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/01/08/2707.aspx) on K. Scott Allen's [blog](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/default.aspx)

**EDIT:**
If you can't use asp utility, you can encrypt config file using [SectionInformation.ProtectSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection.aspx) method.

Sample on codeproject:

[Encryption of Connection Strings inside the Web.config in ASP.Net 2.0](https://secure.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/webconfig.aspx)

Comment: Aku,

unfortunately those links refer to the command line, I am unable to use those as we do not have direct access to the command line.  

If I were to encrypt it on my own machine and then deploy it to the server it will not work as the key will not exist/be different

Comment: He is referring to [Encrypting Custom Configuration Sections](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/01/08/encrypting-custom-configuration-sections.aspx). It is a simple example, the related MSDN article is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

While on the first glance it seems to be straightforward, there are a couple of hurdles I encountered.

So I am providing steps that worked fine for me (to encrypt the **appSettings** section) using the default crypto provider:

**Encrypt** sections in the web.config:

1. Open Admin command shell (run **as administrator!**). The command prompt will be on `C:` which is assumed for the steps below.
   Further assumed is that the application is deployed on `D:\Apps\myApp` - replace this by the path you're using in **step 3.**
2. `cd "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"`, on 32 bit Windows systems use `Framework` instead of `Framework64`
3. `cd /D "D:\Apps\myApp"`
   **Note:** The `/D` switch will change the drive automatically if it is different from your current drive. Here it will change the path and drive, so the current directory will be `D:\Apps\myApp` afterwards.
4. `c:aspnet_regiis -pef appConfig .`

You should see this message:

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
>   Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Encrypting configuration section...
>   Succeeded!

You can also **Decrypt** sections in the web.config:
These are the same steps, but with option `-pdf` instead of `-pef` for aspnet_regiis.

It is also possible to encrypt other sections of your web.config, for example you can **encrypt the connection strings** section via:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"
```

More details about that can be found [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372.aspx)

---

**Note:** The encryption above is **transparent** to your web application, i.e. your web application doesn't recognize that the settings are encrypted. 
You can also choose to use **non-transparent** encryption, for example by using Microsoft's DPAPI or by using [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) along with the Framework's [AES Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Anchor_6). 
How it is done with **DPAPI** I have described [here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15342230/1016343). DPAPI works very similar in a sense that it uses the machine's or user credential's keys. Generally, **non-transparent encryption** gives you more control, for instance you can add a SALT, or you can use a key based on a user's passphrase. If you want to know more about how to generate a key from a passphrase, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307604/1016343).

Answer (score 0):

Use aspnet_setreg.exe http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329290

Comment: This constitutes a link only answer which is against the site rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. Publish your project
2. Open **Developer command Prompt as Administrator**
3. use this command **asp_rigiis -pef "appSettings" "C:\yourPublishPath" -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"**

Comment: I'm pretty sure this uses your machine key so cannot be transported to other machines once its encrypted, in my scenario above, I was unable to run the command line on the host