# Hide app.config

Tags: c#, .net

I want to hide app.config. There are some things like webservice address that shouldn't be visible to user. Maybe it`s some way to put this config in resources?

Thanks

Comment: Tip: Use the apostrophe found to the right of the semi-colon on your keyboard (if it's US). The other accent is used to denote in-line code formatting on Stackoverflow, like `code`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that encrypting app/web config would be a better option.

See this topic for more info [Encrypting appSettings in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200/encrypting-appsettings-in-web-config)

Also codeproject has a plenty of [articles](http://www.google.ru/search?q=codeproject+encrypt+web+config).

Answer (score 1):

Try to figure out whether the settings in your `app.config` file can be applied programmatically.

The most settings in the .NET framework can be used declarative *and* programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really concerned about end-users snooping into the configuration details of your program, it will be *very* hard to hide such information (even if it's contained in code since it can be reverse compiled using tools like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)). You can only make it harder by applying some encryption scheme, like obfuscation that encrypts the internal string table of your assembly. Then again, it's easy to use a packet sniffer tool to obtain the remote URI your program is communicating with.

Comment: Yes, I know that there is always some way to get this kind of information but there is now need to give users opportunity to change some settings

Comment: Then it shouldn't be in the configuration file.