# How to encrypt username and password in Web.config in C# 2.0

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have the entries below in my Web.config and I am using .NET 2.0 and C# for coding.

```
 <add key="userName" value="s752549"/>
 <add key="userPassword" value="Delhi@007"/>
```

Now I want this to be encrypted so that nobody can see it, and also these passwords may change frequently (every fifteen days).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting Web.Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075245/encrypting-web-config)

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200/encrypting-appsettings-in-web-config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypting appSettings in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200/encrypting-appsettings-in-web-config)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could put the username and password into a separate section and encrypt this section only. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="secureAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="Host" value="www.foo.com" />
        <add key="Token" value="qwerqwre" />
        <add key="AccountId" value="123" />
        <add key="DepartmentId" value="456" />
        <add key="SessionEmail" value="foo@foo.com" />
        <add key="DefaultFolder" value="789" />  
    </appSettings>

    <secureAppSettings>
        <add key="userName" value="s752549"/>
        <add key="userPassword" value="Delhi@007"/>

    </secureAppSettings>  
</configuration>
```

and then use aspnet_regiis

```
For Ex: 
aspnet_regiis -pef secureAppSettings . -prov DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
```

Comment: How to give path of webconfig in aspnet_regiis

Comment: And also can you please let me know how to get the encrypted values in our .net code.

Comment: check this for more detail: 

http://diablopup.blogspot.com/2007/04/aspnetregiis-encryptdecrypt-webconfig.html

get vlaues like this 
string userName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["userName"];

Comment: As a side note, you could choose to encrypt the entire "appSettings".  You don't specifically need a separate region, which keeps your code simple.  This is how my project currently does encryption (we also encrypt the connection strings).

Answer (score 14):

Just wanted to add to this, the marked answer was 99% complete, but it didn't provide how to specify the location of the web config.  Rather than root around the internet, thought I'd just post the complete command.  As such, here is the command I executed

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pef "secureAppSettings" "C:\MyLocalPublishDirectory\MyApp" -prov DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Protect / Unprotect entire config sections in .NET.

For more info see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38188/Encrypt-Your-Web-config-Please.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you could use aspnet_regiis, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=VS.80).aspx