# How to encrypt username/password for session

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, httpwebrequest

I am making a call to a 3rd party service via https (using `HttpWebRequest` and sending a username, password in order to return a **token** which is then needed to make future requests for data). The service would only be required to list items on a public ASPNet website.

There will be no database involved so session or cookies would be storing the token.

To get the token I send a POST request which includes the username/password but I can see these details (username/password) in Fiddler (headers text tab I think but can confirm if anyone asks) - personally I thought I shouldn't? When I make a GET request to get the items I send the token and all works.

So am I supposed to encrypt the username/password somehow before making retrieving the token? If yes how would I do that?

I just feel that anyone could check the POST request and see what's going on. I could be wrong but happy to test any theories.

**Edit 1**

Here is the code i am sending the POST request. Please note the username and password along with the URL which is https

```
    private string UsernamePassword()
    {
        string un = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            User = "abc",
            Password = "123"
        });

        return un;
    }

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://site.data.com");

        wr.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
        wr.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
        wr.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
        wr.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");

        wr.Accept = "application/json";
        wr.ContentType = "application/json";

        byte[] data = null;

        wr.Method = "POST";
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UsernamePassword());
        wr.ContentLength = data.Length;
        wr.KeepAlive = true;          
        wr.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = wr.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
            {
                var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(httpResponse.CharacterSet);
```

Comment: That's what TLS/https is for.

Comment: try to understand that where you need to use GET and where you have to use POST. do that you will have answer to this question.

Comment: @germi so do you mean I just add some code to transfer the username/password over TLS?

Comment: @ajay Kumar - please re-read the question, I have clearly stated where I'm doing a post/get request

Comment: @Computer HTTPS should be the default by now - if you're transmitting credentials in the clear over HTTP you're doing it wrong. TLS takes care of encrypting the data - that's what it's there for, so one should use it.

Answer (score 3):

@germi is right. That's exactly what TLS/Https is for. The fact that *you* can see the content of your https request doesn't mean *anyone* can.

As long as your endpoint is using [https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) (and not http), the exchange will happen over an encrypted channel. If you want to verify, install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I've amended my original post to contain the code im sending. It does have the URL set as https but is there anything else i need to add?

Comment: @Computer don't store the username password in the code. Though you're not accessing a database, it's the same problem as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685206/how-do-i-safely-store-database-login-and-password-in-a-c-sharp-application   Have look at the answer there for further information on how to deal with that.

Comment: I will look into that article shortly. The password is coming from the Web.config (but not encrypted) so i use ConfigurationManager to get the value and pass it into UsernamePassword code.

Comment: @Computer *don't* do that. That functionality is rarely used and seldom in production. The doc page you found this explains this is only for development purposes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos are you suggesting not to store it in the config file unencrypted? if so i am currently looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291322/how-to-encrypt-username-and-password-in-web-config-in-c-sharp-2-0 to encrypt which was led from the article posted above

Comment: Don't copy code without understanding what it's doing. Don't store accounts in web.config *at all*. You'll *have* to change account passwords at some point. Having to redeploy or even edit in production and recycle your site isn't a great idea. Read [Copying code from Stack Overflow? You might be spreading security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/)

Comment: And don't tread SO *answers* as if they were tutorials, documentation or even blog posts. They aren't

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The code i posted was shortened for ease of readability. I found this article which allows me to encrypt my config https://goenning.net/2014/03/09/how-to-safely-store-configuration-settings-in-webconfig/