# Base 64 encoding in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I have inherited some C# code. This code needs to upload a picture to a web service. This code saves the bytes of picture into `byte[]` called `ImageBytes`. To ensure the greatest portability, I want to first encode the `ImageBytes` into a base 64 encoded string. I believe the following code is doing that, however, I'm not sure. Can someone please verify if my assumption is correct?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
this.ImageBytes.ToList<byte>().ForEach(x => sb.AppendFormat("{0}.", Convert.ToUInt32(x)));
```

Is this code converting my `byte[]` into a base 64 encoded string?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it will just give you all the bytes in decimal (base 10) with dots between them, like `162.239.5.104.86.`. Just as if you had said `String.Join(".", this.ImageBytes)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use methods `System.Convert.ToBase64String()` and `System.Convert.FromBase64String()`
for example

```
public static string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
{
   byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
   return Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
}

public static string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
{
  byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
  return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Convert.ToBase64String()` method. It takes a byte array as parameter and returns the converted string.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's just converting it to a list of integers.

Use [Convert.ToBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).  Assuming `ImageBytes` is a `byte[]`:

```
var base64Output = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageBytes);
```