# How to get "Manage User Secrets" in a .NET Core console-application?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, visual-studio-2017

When I create a new ASP .NET Core **Web**-Application, I can right-click the project in Visual Studio, and I see a context-menu entry called "Manage User Secrets".

When I create a new .NET Core **Console**-Application, I don't see this context-menu entry.

However, a "Web"-Application shows as "console" application in the project settings. Is there any way I can get this context-menu entry in a console-application ?

Comment: Powershell gist to use as an external command in VS: https://gist.github.com/Zonciu/0b5cf2356b798cd82af1a6e92443b8cb

Comment: official msdn has an answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows

Answer (score 66):

"Manage user secrets" from a right click is only available in web projects.

There is a slightly different process for console applications

It requires manually typing the required elements into your csproj file then adding secrets through the PMC

I have outlined the process that worked for me in my current project step by step in this blog post :

https://medium.com/@granthair5/how-to-add-and-use-user-secrets-to-a-net-core-console-app-a0f169a8713f

*tl;dr*

**Step 1**

Right click project and hit edit projectName.csproj

**Step 2**

add `<UserSecretsId>Insert New Guid Here</UserSecretsId>` into csproj under TargetFramework

add `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0"/>` within Item Group in csproj

**Step 3**

Open PowerShell (admin) cd into project directory and

enter `dotnet user-secrets set YourSecretName "YourSecretContent"`

This will create a secrets.json file in:

```
%APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\<userSecretsId>\secrets.json
```

Where userSecretsId = the new Guid you created for your csproj

**Step 4**

Open secrets.json and edit to look similar to this

```
{
 "YourClassName":{
    "Secret1":"Secret1 Content",
    "Secret2":"Secret2 Content"
   }
}
```

By adding the name of your class you can then bind your secrets to an object to be used.

Create a basic POCO with the same name that you just used in your JSON.

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class YourClassName
    {
        public string Secret1 { get; set; }
        public string Secret2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Step 5**

Add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` Nuget package to project

Add

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddUserSecrets<YourClassName>()
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

&

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()
.Configure<YourClassName>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(YourClassName)))
.AddOptions()
.BuildServiceProvider();

services.GetService<SecretConsumer>();
```

To your Program.cs file.

Then  inject `IOptions<YourClassName>` into the constructor of your class

```
private readonly YourClassName _secrets;

public SecretConsumer(IOptions<YourClassName> secrets)
{
  _secrets = secrets.Value;
}
```

Then access secrets by using `_secrets.Secret1;`

---

Thanks to Patric for pointing out that `services.GetService<NameOfClass>();` should be `services.GetService<SecretConsumer>();`

Comment: This is the approach that we used too and it works nicely. It has the added benefit of being the most compatible approach with the (expected) fix that the VS team will eventually make (assuming it will work the same as for Web projects).

Comment: To help this steps, I've published Visual Studio Extensions for UserSecrets Management, called `Open UserSecrets`. I hope it helps you.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=guitarrapc.OpenUserSecrets

Comment: Shouldn't "services.GetService<NameOfClass>();" be "services.GetService<SecretConsumer>();" ?

Comment: @Patric thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the answer

Comment: I'm trying this with a .NET 5 WinForms test app, the `var service = new ServiceCollection();` line requires a `using System.Web.Services.Description;` from `System.Web.Services` which just stalls at the "Executing Suggested Action" modal dialog box and never ends. Is this reference required? It's not mentioned in the article or steps above. (Yes, I have included the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` NuGet package.)

Comment: Excellent solution, works very well!

Comment: Working fine! Two notes: 1. DotNetCliToolReference needs to be placed in the ItemGroups where the other package references are. 2. After adding GUID and DotNetCliToolReference, reload the csproj file - then you can right click on it and select "Manage User Secrets", which will create the secrets.json file for you. Just an alternative way instead of using the console (it will work for example in test projects too - after you've edited the csproj file as described). Finally, a useful link: [read user secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062080/cannot-read-user-secrets-in-net-core-2-1)

Answer (score 41):

Dotnet Core 3.1 - simplest method I have found in situations when I just need to hide a password.
Create user secrets using command line from project folder

```
dotnet user-secrets init
dotnet user-secrets set mailpassword password1
```

in Program.cs

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddUserSecrets<Program>().Build();
            
var secretProvider = config.Providers.First();
secretProvider.TryGet("mailpassword", out var secretPass);

//'secretPass' should now contain the password
//if the "mailpassword" secret is not found, then 'secretPass' will be null
```

If you are doing more things with configuration you may need to adjust the .First()

Comment: In case anyone wanted to look at the official docs on how this method is done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=linux#secret-manager

Comment: I'm not sure why [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62972670/2) was necessary to explain what's already known about how `out` variables work, but ok...

Answer (score 28):

`Manage User Secrets` is available from the context menu of .NET Core Console projects (not just ASP.NET Core projects) since Visual Studio 2019 (verified in version 16.1.3), once you reference the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` NuGet.

Comment: After testing, for me (VS2019 enterprise v16.2) it only appears after adding the package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets'

Comment: In 16.4.4, it seems the option is visible for all projects, and prompts you to install the package if necessary. Thanks for the answer, @Rabadash8820!

Comment: Docs on how to achieve this using the command line for VS Code users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=linux#secret-manager

Answer (score 9):

1.Add to your project file (Prior to dotnet 2.1 only):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

2.Set

```
 <PropertyGroup>
     <UserSecretsId>a random user id: manually add</UserSecretsId>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

3. Move to the migration project folder in Package Manager Console and add a key:value like:

   ```
   dotnet user-secrets set "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection" "xxxxx"
   ```

Remember to be in the directory of that project (for Package manager console this means cd'ing into the project, not solution level)

Comment: As a side note, with .NET Core SDK 2.1 the first step will become redundant as you'll get warning `Using DotNetCliToolReference to reference 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools' is obsolete and can be removed from this project. This tool is bundled by default in the .NET Core SDK.`

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click on the project and click edit csproj file.
2. On first line replace `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` and save.

Now you can access to manage user secrets menu, edit it and save. Then you have to restore the first line of the csproj file to its defaults to be again a console app.

It's stupid but it works. Remember replace the usersecretsid property for every project or will just have one `secrets.json` for all your projects.

Comment: It does seem stupid, and it does work - are there unintended side effects?

Comment: I’ve not found any related issues when using it.

Answer (score 4):

1. ###### Install needed packages from cmd/terminal on project root directory

- `dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`
- `dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`

2. ###### Set secrets from cmd/terminal on project root directory

- `dotnet user-secrets init`
- `dotent user-secrets set "DemoApp:ConnectionString" "my connectin string"`

3. ###### Use secrets on the code. Instead `Progam` class in `AddUserSecrets<Progam>` any type from the project can be used.

   - `var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddUserSecrets<Progam>().Build();`
   - `var connectionString = config.GetSection("DemoApp")["ConnectionString"];`

Answer (score 3):

It appears that they haven't added that (at least to Visual Studio 2015) as an option for Console or DLL apps.

You can use this as a work around, **but do so at your own risk**, it will trick Visual Studio into believing that the dll project has Web capabilities as well.

Assuming Windows OS

1. Open File Explorer to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v{Version Number}\DotNet`  **note:** 14.0 is VS 2015, 15.0 is 2017 etc
2. backup the file named `Microsoft.DotNet.targets`
3. Add this line to `Microsoft.DotNet.targets` next to the other `ProjectCabability` tag

   `<ProjectCapability Include="DotNetCoreWeb" />`
4. Save the file, and unload and reload your project / restart visual studio.

You may also need to delete your .suo file and/or your .vs folder

You should now see the context menu. It also changes the icon unfortunately. It seems to build just fine, but this is pretty untested so seriously, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

There is already an <strike>open</strike> closed issue related to this on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7360).

What you can do until they solve it, is to use the command line approach as described on [Visual Studio Code or Command Line: Installing the Secret Manager tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets). This doesn't mean that you get your context menu item but it works nevertheless.

One note, the documentation is referring to `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />` while version `2.0.0` is already out and can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to the answers posted here, if you want a link to your own secrets.json file in your project, you can add the following code to an ItemGroup in your project file:

```
<None Include="$(AppData)\microsoft\UserSecrets\$(UserSecretsId)\secrets.json" Link="secrets.json" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In a new .NET 8 Console App:

Right click `.csproj` in Visual Studio and select "Manage User Secrets". You will then see this dialog:

[image]

It adds the packages `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`.

You can then get values like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
            .Build();

        Console.WriteLine(config["AppSecret"]);
    }
}
```

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows#user-secrets-in-non-web-applications

Answer (score 1):

If it's only needed get the User Secrets configuration, it's enough on the constructor of `YourSecretClass` the follow code:

```cs
public YourSecretClass()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddUserSecrets<Secrets>().Build();

    SecretID = builder.GetSection("SecretID").Value;
    SecretPwd = builder.GetSection("SecretPwd").Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, this context menu entry is available for *both* web (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`) and non-web (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk`) projects,  **but only if you also have the "ASP.NET and web development" workload installed** (you can untick all optional features during setup if you don't need them).

So once you add it via "Tools > Get Tools and Features..." it'll appear on both kinds of projects.

Typically happens to me on a fresh install not requiring to develop web projects by default, but using user secrets in console apps aswell.

Answer (score -3):

How to get “Manage User Secrets” in a .NET Core console-application?

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community with update 3

1. File -> New-> Project
2. Select Console Application (.NET Core)
3. Press CTRL+ALT+L
4. Click on the project to get “Manage User Secrets” it will open up 
   a file called secrets.json

and where you can manually enter user-secrets.

I was able to use command prompt to setup user secrets:

c:\Projects\ConsoleApp2\src\ConsoleApp2>dotnet user-secrets set BrainTree_sandbox:Merchant ID:9rv9mhnb5gh7nnyx