# "Manage User Secrets" context menu item missing

Tags: .net-core

Followed the guide for "Installing the Secret Manager tool" for a .Net Core console application here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?tabs=visual-studio

However, the context menu item "Manage User Secrets" is still not appearing when I right-click on the project.

Is the guide wrong i.e. is there a step not documented in the Microsoft documentation for getting the context menu item "Manage User Secrets"?

Comment: Powershell gist to use as an external command in VS: https://gist.github.com/Zonciu/0b5cf2356b798cd82af1a6e92443b8cb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "Manage User Secrets" in a .NET Core console-application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268265/how-to-get-manage-user-secrets-in-a-net-core-console-application)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you have referenced are categorised under ASPNET core, rather than explicitly for console apps. (I was trying to get this working on a tests project and having the same issue.)

The "Manage User Secrets" context menu item should be available on an ASPNET core project even prior to adding any NuGet packages. For other projects user secrets can be managed on the command line via the `dotnet user-secrets` command instead.

See this git ticket for further comments: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7360