# Alternatives to SecureString?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to use [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-2.2) to store some confidential data.

But I saw [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-2.2#remarks)

> We don't recommend that you use the SecureString class for new development.

So I would like to know if there are alternatives to SecureString?

Comment: From the [GitHub page on Secure String](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md): "Don't use SecureString for new code. When porting code to .NET Core, consider that the contents of the array are not encrypted in memory. The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication."

Answer (score 4):

> Recommendation
>
> Don't use SecureString for new code. When porting code to .NET Core, consider that the contents of the array are not encrypted in memory.
>
> The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and
> instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or
> Windows authentication.

https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

Comment: This doesn't help when credentials are not what is being stored as a secret.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson - Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15342230/1016343). It shows some alternatives.