# asp.net Web deploy: add MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule in .pubxml to encrypt appSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am publishing asp.net web application using web deploy and I need to encrypt connectionsstrings and appsettings in web.config file. So added 
`<MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>true</MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>` in the .pubxml, then connectionstrings are encrypted but not appsettings. I need to encrypt appsettings as well. Can we encrypt appsettings by making some changes in .pubxml or Do we need to do it manually using aspnet_regiis.exe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200/encrypting-appsettings-in-web-config

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars: the link you referred explains about how to encrypt and decrypt using  ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe). But   I am talking about encrypting automatically when publishing using web deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webdeploy can only encrypt connection string. If you want to encrypt appsetting or other sections, you can try using aspnet_regiis command line.

aspnet_regiis -pe "ElementName" -app "/SampleApplication"

Ref: ([http://forums.iis.net/t/1223409.aspx?Encrypting+any+section+of+Web+Config](http://forums.iis.net/t/1223409.aspx?Encrypting%20any%20section%20of%20Web%20Config))